# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User How I solve this error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch all users Except current logged in user in the UsersFragment. But I am facing the error which is given below. & also the java file & Firebase Database.

---

***Error***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.psb.farmersmarket, PID: 13713
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:435)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:203)
        at com.psb.farmersmarket.Fragments.UsersFragment$1.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:107)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

---

***UserFragment.java***

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter adapter;
    private List<User> userList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users,container,false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        userList = new ArrayList<>();

        readUsers();
        return view;
    }

    private void readUsers() {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    if(!user.getUserID().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        userList.add(user);
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this userfragment.java file, this given line generates the error.

```
User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

and the error is

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
```

---

***User.java***

```
public class User {
    private String UserName;
    private String UserPhone;
    private String UserDesc;
    private String UserEmail;
    private String UserID;
    private String imageURL;
    private String search;

    public User(String userName,String userPhone,String userDesc,String userEmail, String userID, String imageURL, String search) {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.UserPhone = userPhone;
        this.UserDesc = userDesc;
        this.UserEmail = userEmail;
        this.UserID = userID;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    @PropertyName("Phone No")
    public String getUserPhone() {
        return UserPhone;
    }

    @PropertyName("Phone No")
    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        UserPhone = userPhone;
    }

    @PropertyName("Description")
    public String getUserDesc() {
        return UserDesc;
    }

    @PropertyName("Description")
    public void setUserDesc(String userDesc) {
        UserDesc = userDesc;
    }

    @PropertyName("email")
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return UserEmail;
    }

    @PropertyName("email")
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        UserEmail = userEmail;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    @PropertyName("imageURL")
    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    @PropertyName("imageURL")
    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }
}
```

---

***DATABASE FILE***

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "77EOhwNHgPbDwSEz1mbHOclUy0o1" : {
      "Description" : "student",
      "Phone No" : "9876543210",
      "email" : "pratikbharad@xyz.com",
      "imageURL" : "default",
      "name" : "Pratik Bharad",
      "search" : "pratik bharad",
      "status" : "offline",
      "user id" : "77EOhwNHgPbDwSEz1mbHOclUy0o1"
    },
    "vjDg7Q9QtgQO0DGM83Dwynk5Caa2" : {
      "Description" : "student",
      "Phone No" : "9876543210",
      "email" : "pratikbharad213@xyz.com",
      "imageURL" : "default",
      "name" : "Pratik",
      "search" : "pratik",
      "status" : "offline",
      "user id" : "vjDg7Q9QtgQO0DGM83Dwynk5Caa2"
    }
  },
}
```

**I very tried to solve this error but the error remains the same
please help me to solve this error.**

Comment: the issue is in parsing the string response to user class

Comment: just a min. sir, I will add the user.java file also.

Comment: I added the user.java file also. now please point out my mistake. sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attaches a listener to `/Users/aSpecificUid`. So in your `onDataChange` the `dataSnapshot` will contain the data for a single user. But your code then loops over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`, which means that each `snapshot` in that loop contains the data for a single property of that user (`Description`, `Phone No`, etc). And when you then call `snapshot.getValue(User.class)`, you're trying to convert a simple string/numeric value to a complete `User` object, which won't work.

The solution is to remove the loop over `getChildren()` from your `onDataChange`:

```
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert firebaseUser != null;
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            assert user != null;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Also: given where you attach the listener, the `if(!user.getUserID().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){` check is not needed, so I removed that.

Going forward, always think of whether the `DataSnapshot` contains a single node, or if it can contain multiple nodes. If it can contain multiple nodes, you will need to loop over `getChildren()`.

---

**Update**: to show "all users but the currently logged in one", you'll need to read the data for all users, and then skip the currently logged in user in the loop.

Since you're already checking the UID in the loop, it should be a matter of attaching the listener to the correct node `/Users`:

```
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
assert firebaseUser != null;
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        userList.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            assert user != null;
            if(!user.getUserID().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                userList.add(user);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: sir, I want all users except the current logged in user, which are stored in my database. & for taking the all user in userAdapter FOR LOOP is mandatory... by using your answer there is only one user fetch.

Comment: If you want all users, you should attach a listener to `/Users`. You can exclude a single child node from the read operation, so you'll have to skip the current user in your application code. Since you already do so in your code, it should be a matter of listening to the correct node in the database. I added this to my answer too.

Comment: now another error is generated. `if(!user.getUserID().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){}` this line generates null object refernce.

Comment: That sounds like your `user` is null, so that you're `DataSnapshot` is not actually pointing to a user's data from the database.

Comment: then how I will fetch the data of all users in `user` variable

Comment: I tried so many times, so many ways. But `user` variable remains null. please, SIR, solve my error.....

Comment: I typically use an auth state listener as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533745/firebase-authentication-auth-state-changed

Answer (score 0):

you can read the data from data snapshot like that

```
 @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String description= dataSnapshot.child("Description").getValue(String.class);
       // also pick the other and then create yours object
}
```

I think the userId might be creating the issue. So surround

```
 User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

with try catch so look for the field which is creating issue. And one thing more, this is better to have no spaces between your variable name like e.g 
`Phone Number` so it should be like `phoneNumber`